# User location not showing in map

Tags: ios5, mkmapview, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I need to diaplay user current location in map with blue dot circle. I used CLLocationManager. But mapview only displayed. I sent custom lat,long. But this lat,long can't displayed in map.

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *vc=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    [self.view addSubview:vc];
    MKMapView *map = [[MKMapView alloc] init]; 
    map.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

    map.showsUserLocation=YES;
  [self.view addSubview:map];
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
   // NSLog(@"OldLocation %f %f", oldLocation.coordinate.latitude, oldLocation.coordinate.longitude);
   // NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [newLocation coordinate];

    NSLog(@"current longitude = %f  ,   current latitude = %f",loc.longitude,loc.latitude);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use InterfaceBuilder, drop a map view onto your screen, tick the box next to shows user location.

Also, you don't need a locationmanager for showing the user location, the mapview will take care of that.